# Парсинг JSON в Javascript из Python

Tags: javascript, python, json

Передаю данные с сервера. 
Получаю дату на клиенте.

Паршу:

```
var msg = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(msg);
```

Получаю:

```
{'id': 17, 'created_at': None, 'modified_at': None, 'first_name': 'ccc', 'last_name': 'zzzzzzzzzxxxxxxxxx', 'full_name': 'xxxxxxxxxccc', 'email': None, 'password': None, 'active': True, 'confirmed_at': None, 'last_login_at': None, 'current_login_at': None, 'last_login_ip': None, 'current_login_ip': None, 'login_count': None, 'created_by': None}
```

Но при попытке получить значение по ключу,
`msg.id` либо же `msg["id"]`, в ответ получаю `undefined`

Предполагаю, что дело в "валидности", либо же в наличии None.

Подскажите, что делать?
Желательно, чтобы данные не пришлось изменять на стороне сервера.

Заранее спасибо, и извиняюсь за банальный вопрос.

Comment: `console.log(data);`? и что это за `None`, `True` и одинарные кавычки?

Comment: console.log(data) возвращает  "{'id': 17, 'created_at': None, 'modified_at': None, 'first_name': 'cccasd', 'last_name': 'zzzzzzzzzxxxxxxxxx', 'full_name': 'xxxxxxxxxccc', 'email': None, 'password': None, 'active': True, 'confirmed_at': None, 'last_login_at': None, 'current_login_at': None, 'last_login_ip': None, 'current_login_ip': None, 'login_count': None, 'created_by': None}"

Comment: None и True - такими данные приходят с бэкенда

Comment: Уверен, что одинарные кавычки не играют роли.

Comment: что выводит: `console.log(typeof msg);`

Comment: @Grundy - до него - `console.log(msg);`, вероятно, дело не доходит

Comment: В data - json строка, в которой не json.

Comment: console.log(typeof data) console.log(typeof msg) возвращает string

Comment: _console.log(typeof msg) возвращает string_ - вот по этому и не можешь поля получить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var newData = data.replace(/\'/g, "\""); //  Меняем кавычки
newData = newData.replace(/\None/g, "null");  // Меняем None на null
newData = newData.replace(/\True/g, "true"); // Меняем True на trur
newData = newData.substr(1, newData.length-2); // Обрезаем первые и последние кавычки

var msg = JSON.parse(newData);
console.log(msg);
```

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 4 of the JSON

Comment: Строка получилась такой:
"{"id": 17, "created_at": null, "modified_at": null, "first_name": "12356", "last_name": "121212zzzzzzasdasdasd", "full_name": "1", "email": null, "password": null, "active": false, "confirmed_at": null, "last_login_at": null, "current_login_at": null, "last_login_ip": null, "current_login_ip": null, "login_count": null, "created_by": null}"

Comment: Кавычки которые в начале и в конце это часть текста?

Comment: Это строка после замены и до преобразования.

Comment: Выведи результат console.log(data[0], data[data.length-1])

Comment: Выводит " ",  но я не понимаю, что делает console.log(data[0], data[data.length-1])

Comment: выводит первый и последний символ строки

Comment: Обновил ответ, добавил обрезку substr(1, newData.length-2);

Comment: Большое спасибо.
А что делает newData.substr(1, newData.length-2); ?

Comment: Обрезает строку с второго символа до предпоследнего. http://javascript.ru/string/substr

Comment: Добавьте в ваш ответ описание вашего решения, чтобы пользователям было легче понять ваш ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Есть несколько основных правил для создания строки JSON:

1. Строка JSON содержит либо массив значений, либо объект (ассоциативный массив пар имя/значение).
2. Массив заключается в квадратные скобки ([ и ]) и содержит разделенный запятой список значений.
3. Объект заключается в фигурные скобки ({ и }) и содержит разделенный запятой список пар имя/значение.
4. Пара имя/значение состоит из имени поля, заключенного в двойные кавычки, за которым следует двоеточие (:) и значение поля.
5. Значение в массиве или объекте может быть:

   - Числом (целым или с плавающей точкой)
   - Строкой (в двойных кавычках)
   - Логическим значением (true или false)
   - Другим массивом (заключенным в квадратные скобки)
   - Другой объект (заключенный в фигурные скобки)
   - Значение null

Чтобы включить двойные кавычки в строку, нужно использовать обратную косую черту: \". Так же, как и во многих языках программирования, можно помещать управляющие символы и шестнадцатеричные коды в строку, предваряя их обратной косой чертой.

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен, что это сработает, и, вероятно, это не безопасно, но можно попробовать вот так:

var None = null;
var True = true;
eval("var msg = " + data);